# cakephp looping only save first row of data, others row not saving

Tags: loops, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Looping to save each column field [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUMJ6.png)[pic6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Tgq.jpg):

Please help, i using cake php version 2.0, try to do looping to save each column, but only the first row data save, the data should be save like attached picture1.Hope someone can help, i tried to figure out 2 weeks. V_COUNT i hardcode the number to 23.

```
if($this->IPI->save($this->request->data))
{
    $table_name = 'IPI_V';
    $this->IPI->setSource($table_name);
    for($i=1;$i<=$this->request->data['IPI']['V_COUNT'];$i++)
    {
        if($i<10){$i = '0'. $i;}

        if(($this->request->data['IPI']['Quantity'.$i])!=NULL)
        {

            $this->request->data['IPI']['Type_Defect'] = $this->request->data['IPI']['Type_Defect'.$i];     
            $this->request->data['IPI']['CAT'] = $this->request->data['IPI']['CAT'.$i];
            $this->request->data['IPI']['Defect'] = $this->request->data['IPI']['Defect'.$i];
            $this->request->data['IPI']['Quantity'] = $this->request->data['IPI']['Quantity'.$i];
            $this->IPI->create();
            $this->IPI->save($this->request->data);
        }

    }
```

Comment: instead of if(($this->request->data['IPI']['Quantity'.$i])!=NULL) try using if(!empty($this->request->data['IPI']['Quantity'][$i])) or else please share the output that you are getting in the request

Comment: Dear Rohit, the result still the same, only saved one row, this code i've tried before.output pls refer picture2.

Comment: Ok, Can you please do a pr($this->request->data) and show me the output from your request data.

Comment: Dear Rohit, please refer picture3.Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using `saveMany()` to save multiple rows here?

Comment: Dear drmonkey, if i use saveMany () the system cannot save.

Comment: please check my answer below that should serve your purpose.

Comment: @user3719378 just looking at your example code again. Why are you saving the request data multiple times (first in your `if` statement and then again in your `for` loop)? If you had your request data (presumably from a form) in the correct format to begin with you could probably achieve what you want to do in a few lines.  Could you perhaps update your question with an explanation of what you want to actually do here!

Comment: This is extremely messy. What exactly are you trying to do and what do the database tables look like? If you're trying to save multiple rows of the same data to the same table, then you should be using saveMany().

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($this->IPI->save($this->request->data))
    {
         $table_name = 'IPI_V';
          for($i=1;$i<=$this->request->data['IPI']['V_COUNT'];$i++)
        {
        $data = array();
        if($i<10){$i = '0'. $i;}

        if(($this->request->data['IPI']['Quantity'.$i])!=NULL)

        {

        $data['IPI']['Type_Defect'] = $this->request->data['IPI']['Type_Defect'.$i];     
        $data['IPI']['CAT'] = $this->request->data['IPI']['CAT'.$i];
        $data['IPI']['Defect'] = $this->request->data['IPI']['Defect'.$i];
        $data['IPI']['Quantity'] = $this->request->data['IPI']['Quantity'.$i];

          $this->IPI->setSource($table_name);
        $this->IPI->create();
        $this->IPI->save($data);
        }

        }
```

Comment: Dear Rohit, sorry to say the result still the same, one row saved.

Comment: before the create can you do a pr($data) and comment out the save and show me a picture that are you getting the data everytime or not

Comment: Dear Rohit, pls refer picture4.Thanks.

Comment: It seems the same as before, please use my code and let me see the $data inside the for loop.

Comment: Dear Rohit, i already follow the steps you provided, the $data result inside still the same. Pls refer pic5.

Comment: This cannot be the case, as in $data we are only assigning 4 keys and their values, but in your screenshot there are many keys. I think you are confused. I am asking you to comment out ` $this->IPI->create();
        $this->IPI->save($data);` and in place of that do a pr($data); in my code and then grab a screenshot and share. I don't know from where you are taking up the screenshots.

Comment: Dear Rohit, sorry for late reply,pls find attached pic6 for the result.thanks